# "Undefined variable" error

Tags: php

I get the error undefined variable err. I've tried isset here but maybe my code is wrong.

```
 if(err ==1)
 {  
      $record = $_POST;
      foreach($record as $key=$val) $record[$key] = stripslashes($val);
      $msg ="Please fill the empty field";
 }
```

Comment: Try to use a more descriptive title next time ;)

Comment: In your `foreach` loop, it should be `$key => $val` instead of `$key = $val`

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have defined "err" as constant somewhere or use $err instead of err.

Answer (score 0):

in php variable have prefix $ symbol or err must be constant,but it is good practice to use constant name as Capital letters

try this code

```
     if( isset($err)  && $err == 1 )
     {  
          $record = $_POST;
          foreach($record as $key=>$val) $record[$key] = stripslashes($val);
          $msg ="Please fill the empty field";
     }
```

**EDIT**

try to check variable is exist or not using isset()

Comment: I have tried your recommendation and still get the same error undefined variable err. I even copied and pasted your code as is.

Comment: try updated code, it may happen that you have not assigned $err variable and directly checking in if condition

Answer (score 0):

There is Two mistrake in your code

```
        1. Forget $ sign which is neccessary in PHP

        2. Wrong syntax for foreach loop there will be => sign instead of =
```

// so right code is

> ```
> if($err ==1)
> {
>   $record = $_POST;
>   foreach($record as $key=>$val) 
>       $record[$key] = stripslashes($val); 
>
>   $msg ="Please fill the empty field"; 
> }
> ```

Comment: still get undefined variable err

Comment: Show from where you get this $err. Show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting *undefined* is because where you define your `err` variable you are forgetting to create it as `$err`.

You need to change **every place** in your code where you have `err` variable to `$err`, not just in the place you have shown in this question. That's why you're still getting *undefined* after trying the solutions here, because you're only changing to `$err` in one place.

Comment: I have rechecked my entire code and every place it is $err and my error remains in the same line

Comment: @MogamatToufa Did you try changing `if ($err == 1)` to `if (isset($err))`?